# Subset of T2 space X

Tags: general-topology

1)If I have set (X,T) Hausdorff , then any (A,U) \subset in X is Hausdorff,where T and U are any topologies? 
2)Why (R,Tusual) is locally compact?

Comment: 1) is obviously not true unless there's some relationship between $T$ and $U$, like for example $T_{|A}\subseteq U$ and 2) follows from the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is generated by open balls which are relatively compact (which is a consequence of Weierstrass theorem).

Comment: @freakish i cant read what you meant after *for example* in proof 1 can u rewrite it please?

Comment: By $T_{|A}$ I mean the subspace topology relative to $A$. Other than that topologies are sets so they can contain each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a Hausdorff space and $A \subseteq X$ is a subspace, in the subspace topology, then $A$ is also Hausdorff: let $a_1, a_2 \in A$ be distinct points. Then these are distinct points in $X$ and so there are open $U,V \in \mathcal{T}$ such that $a_1 \in U, a_2 \in V, U \cap V = \emptyset$. Then $U \cap A$ and $A \cap V$ are open in the subspace topology on $A$ (by definition) and are still disjoint, and still contain $a_1,a_2$ resp. So $A$ is also Hausdorff in the subspace topology.
2. Is clear: any $x \in \Bbb R$ has a local base of open sets of the form $(x-r,x+r)$, $r>0$ and these have compact closures $[x-r,x+r]$ (closed and bounded implies compact in $\Bbb R$.), or otherwise put, the sets $[x-r,x+r]$ form a local base of compact neighbourhoods at $x$.

Comment: then u r saying that whenever (X,T) is T2 , then so is (A,U) where A subset in X and U is an arbitrary topology?

Comment: @sarafkh No, the subspace topology, as I make clear.

Comment: it is the relative topology?

Comment: @sarafkh That's another name for it, yes.

Comment: I mean i know that (R,Tusual) is T2 , then so is (Q,Tusual) !!! but it is the same topology though! So how ?

Comment: @sarafkh There not the same topology! But on $\Bbb Q$ the subspace topology is also the one induced by the order and the restricted metric.

Comment: i didnt understand your last comment can u explain plz

Comment: @sarafkh a topology on $\Bbb R$ is not the same on $\\Bbb Q$. Agreed?

Comment: But the dr put (Q,usual top) in the exercise , so how? did he mean the usual topo here as the relative top? i.e ]a,b[ΠQ

Comment: @sarafkh the usual topology on $\Bbb Q$ indeed is the relative topology of $\Bbb R$ inherited on the rationals. So this fact applies to that case in particular.

Comment: Hi . can u answer my unrelated question please?Let X be a set . Let $A \subset X $ .The A is open $\iff$ $there exists$ V $\in$ $N(x) \forall x \in A s.t x \in V \subset A$ . Then shall V be an open neighborhood? Or is it enough to be only a neighborhood?